# Textract won't read .doc files in Greek

Tags: python, .doc

I am trying to read a bunch of .doc files in Python to run some text analysis. The docs [(an example of which is attached here)](https://1drv.ms/w/s!Ai7TF-zwGitqhBX_RJePvy8hf3qB) contain certain non-ascii characters in Greek (for which i do not know the encoding MS Word uses).

Code i am using:

```
import textract
text = textract.process("path_to_sample.doc", extension = 'doc', encoding = "utf_8")
```

I tried many encoding arguments but non have worked.

Any ideas?

Comment: [Here's a quick guide](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Choose-text-encoding-when-you-open-and-save-files-60d59c21-88b5-4006-831c-d536d42fd861) to encoding in Microsoft Word -- per the table near the bottom, it looks like if the Greek isn't encoded in Unicode, then it'll be in Windows 1253.

Comment: Positively weird. If you look at your file, it is just your basic 2-byte encoding for a Unicode block (the default is a 1-byte encoding, with the character set encoding defined in the basic table), so *any* text extractor should not have to do *anything* special. However, both `textract` as well as plain `antiword` (called from the command line) seem to silently replace non-ASCII characters in such blocks with `?`...

Comment: A possible solution: convert your `.doc` to the more substantially supported (and newer) `.docx`, then use `python-docx`.

Comment: @usr2564301 Yes that is an obvious solution (as well as plain text) and it works like a charm but the problem is i have more than 2500 files like that. Is there a programmatic way to do that through python?

Comment: Of course there is, even if you have to read [Microsoft's tough documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc313153(v=office.12).aspx) on the Word format. But such an answer would be *far* too long for Stack Overflow... FYI, I wrote my own OLE-wrapper a while ago and adjusting it for Word's `WordDocument` stream gave me `This text is a test @  ánti çSã GO.ΣΗΜΕΙΩΣΗ ...` (etc.) so yeah, it is *definitely* possible.

Comment: I created library to extract text from doc files
https://github.com/uvoteam/libdoc